# set up but do not evaluate the def integral of the volume of solid obtained by revolving the region bounded by

Tags: calculus, integration

Set up but do not evaluate the definite integral of the volume of solid obtained by revolving the region bounded by $x = y^2-y$ and the $y$ axis about the line $y=2$.

I set it up and got $$2\pi \int_0^1 (2-y)(y^2-y)dy$$

but the answer is saying $$2\pi\int_0^1 (2-y)(-(y^2-y))dy$$

I went over this question many times, even with a tutor, and they agree with me. So why is the $y^2-y$ negative?

Comment: I've edited your post to include MathJax. Please verify that it's correct.

Comment: its correct____

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because for $0 \lt y \lt 1, y \gt y^2$ so the integrand in the second is positive.

Answer (score 1):

Draw the region we are rotating. Note that it lives to the left of the $t$-axis.

You are using Cylindrical Shells, and have the radius right. But the "height" of the shell is $y-y^2$. Note that $y^2-y$ is *negative* in our interval.

Another way of thinking about it is that the $x$ coordinate travels
**from** $x=y^2-y$ **to** $x=0$. So the amount of travel is $0-(y^2-y)=y-y^2$.

Comment: do you think you can show me a graph of the region being rotated?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha will do it for you, for free. I will describe it in words. The curve $x=y^2-y$ is a rightward opening parabola, with axis parallel to the $x$-axis (the axis is the line $y=1/2$). A small part of the parabola is to the left of the $y$-axis. It is that chunk, ending on the right at the $y$-axis, that we are rotating. In a number of volume or area problems, the geometry is relevant. I can't solve such problems without making a sketch.